# The ASP.NET MVC controller converts percentage characters of the received parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, push-notification, windows-store-apps

I am sending a POST message to an ASP.NET MVC controller. I include this parameter:

Uri=https://db3.notify.windows.com/?token=AgYAAACAP1c6eba3Vl2GSi5fEDQuX2syWQzxtK5rJ2%2f28ZqItAU0MvAyu1PKI%2bd1bDMeoS3ThbZoNtF07eHaSbvYS%2f6Yyiejrz5cO0LalzuWEQXsSYw%3d

The parameter has some characters like "%2f" or "%3d" that are converted by the framework when I read it inside the controller, so I get a wrong value.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string Uri)
{
   // ...
}
```

Wrong value:

Uri=https://db3.notify.windows.com/?token=AgYAAACAP1c6eba3Vl2GSi5fEDQuX2syWQzxtK5rJ2/28ZqItAU0MvAyu1PKI+d1bDMeoS3ThbZoNtF07eHaSbvYS/6Yyiejrz5cO0LalzuWEQXsSYw=

Conversion:

%2f -> /

%2b -> +

%3d -> =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, MVC URL decodes the action parameters. That's by design. If you need to keep them URL encoded, then you need to URL encode them before passing into something like `Html.ActionLink`, so that they'll essentially be URL encoded twice.

Comment: Exactly, I had to encode the URL before sending it to the ASP.NET MVC controller. The client is a Windows Store app so I have used: System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(uri)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` (documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
string decodedUri = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Uri);
```